# what happens if I have an empty return statement inside a useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

lets say I have a small useEffect hook -

```
useEffect(()=>
    if(!someVariable) return;
      doSomething(someVariable);
),[someVariable]);
```

what happens when I return without any cleanup function or anything else? is it wrong? gonna create bugs?

I've tried to search the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) but there's nothing about it, and technically it works great, but I wanna be sure

Comment: If you return nothing, then no cleanup will happen. It will only create a bug if you need to clean something up

Comment: It depends on what something `doSomething` does. If you don't have anything that needs cleaning up, you don't need to return a clean up function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not returning a clean up function, nor do I try to, I'm asking if it will create a bug if I'm returning nothing at all inside a useEffect hook - just as the first line inside the useEffect shows. literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's an answer in JS docs about it that has nothing to do with react.js -

["A function without a return statement will return a default value. In the case of a constructor called with the new keyword, the default value is the value of its this parameter. For all other functions, the default return value is undefined"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

so it turns out that either way any function in JS return at least undefined value (implicitly) so me doing so in a useEffect has no effect (pun intended)